# Преобразование типов в const char*

Tags: c++, массивы, типы-данных

Нужна помощь в приведении к правильному типу данных.
При помощи строкового типа я получаю список файлов в папке. Далее я хочу передавать имя файла в `FILE*`чтобы в дальнейшем с ним работать. И вот уже битый час бьюсь в попытке преобразовать тип. Например на вот такую конструкцию он у меня ругается на то что не может считать символы строки
`std::string files;
const char * conv_files = files.c_str();`

```
    // Директория для отображения
string dir = string(".");
// Вектор в который помещаются имена файлов
vector<string> files = vector<string>();

getdir(dir, files);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
{
    cout << files[i] << endl;

    FILE *file;
    errno_t err;
    err = fopen_s(&file, "3285.wav", "rb");
    if (err)
    {
        printf_s("Failed open file, error %d", err);
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: у Вас files - это вектор строк, если нужно получить одно имя файла, то нужно где то так `files[index].c_str()`

Comment: Согласен, как раз через `cout << files[i] << endl;` у меня выводится список файлов
а с `const char` так не выйдет, потому что выражение должно иметь константное значение(((

Comment: может покажете более полный пример? Но почему Вы считаете, что оно не будет работать - я не знаю. BTW: printf_s, fopen_s и подобные - это си. Лучше используйте их с++ аналоги.

Comment: https://hello-site.ru/share/oshibka-preobrazovaniya-tipov/
вот выложил более полный листинг

Comment: "потому что выражение должно иметь константное значение" - это вы о чем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я посмотрел на сорцы. В них чудо код, который заставляет усомниться в компиляторе. Посмотрим на кусок

```
vector<string> files = vector<string>();

    getdir(dir, files);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << files[i] << endl;

        std::string files;
        const char * conv_files = files.c_str();


        FILE *file;
        errno_t err;
        err = fopen_s(&file, "3285.wav", "rb"); // сюда вместо 3285.wav я хочу передать files[i]
```

Я никак не мог понять, почему когда я пишу вот так

```
err = fopen_s(&file, files[i].c_str(), "rb");
```

оно ругается. А ларчик открывается просто - в данном месте files уже не вектор строк, а просто строка. И достаточно удалить две ненужные строки

```
std::string files;
const char * conv_files = files.c_str();
```

как все начинает компилироваться.

P.S. Правда по коду используются "секюрные функции" с префиксом _s, которые нормальными компиляторами абсолютно не поддерживаются с такими сигнатурами. Поэтому, мне пришлось немного их поправить:)

Comment: этим самым я пытался перевести типы, но в дальнейшем натыкался на еще большее количество ошибок
и кстати даже и в голову не приходило столь элегантное решение) спасибо)

Comment: А подскажите еще такой вопрос, я хочу передать из функции `getdir` директорию где лежит файл, использую указатель на переменную и передаю его в другую функцию, причем обе переменные имеют строковый тип, но почему-то получаю последовательность байт кода(((

Comment: Видимо используется указатель на локальную переменную?

Comment: да, так как передаю из `getdir` в `main`

Comment: делайте минимальный пример и создавайте новый вопрос. Модуль телепатии сегодня и так загружен.

Answer (score 1):

Нет никакой проблемы в том, чтобы написать

```
err = fopen_s(&file, files[i].c_str(), "rb");
```

Поэтому не ясно, в чем заключается ваше затруднение.

Comment: смотрите мой ответ:) автор спрятал пару строк, прям как для собеседования.

Comment: я просто волосы рву на себе))) сколько времени убил на столь простое решение)))) спасибо